# Error code 1060: Trying to merge tables so as to impute the missing values - but always get an error duplicate column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to merge tables several tables so that I can impute the missing data in the final table.

But, I am always getting the duplicate column 'column name'.

What I did is :

- I did Innerjoin several tables and aliased every derived table . And used it

Its an assignment work, so can't share much details, but need be I will try to change variables and share the code.

Would be glad if some one has experience on this error handling?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71454114/edit) to show your SQL statement, your DB schema, and the error message you received.

Comment: Did you also alias column names ?